# expressão regular php

Tags: php, regex, libcurl

estou tentando pegar todo um codigo fonte de um site.

usando CURL usei a expressão regular

```
    preg_match('/<html>(.*)<\/html>/i', $resultado, $codigo);
    echo $codigo = $codigo[1];
```

porem, não deu certo... onde esta o erro?

Comment: Qual é parte que vc quer pegar?

Comment: quero pegar todo o codigo fonte. 100% dele

Comment: O curl já não retorna isso?

Comment: usando o codigo que postei acima, o resultado é:

´Notice: Undefined offset: 1´

Comment: O `file_get_contents` não seria mais fácil/prático pra você?

Comment: verificou o conteúdo de `$resultado` ? veja o que aparece com `highlight_string($resultado);`

Comment: @Florida ele está usando CURL

Comment: florida, dando ECHO no file_get_contents, aparece a pagina, e nao o codigo dela.

Comment: A página pode aparecer pq foi renderizada pelo navegador, se vc armazenar ela em uma variável pode manipular a vontade.

Comment: @rray resolveu.... muito obrigado... usando o highlight_string($resultado) apareceu o codigo inteiro da pagina.... muito obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode exibir o código fonte de um ´página com `highlight_string()`, isso evita que ele seja renderizado pelo navegador, então basta algo como:

```
highlight_string($resultado);
```

Comment: <CONTEUDO>
<CONTEUDO>
 <PONTO1>
   <CONTEUDO>
   <CONTEUDO>
 <PONTO2>
<CONTEUDO>

Como que eu faço para obter como resultado apenas o CONTEUDO que estão entre o PONTO1 e PONTO2?